# Homemade Li-ion charger

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, constant-current

I am trying to build a lithium battery charger (Li-Ion) for charging banks of 6s batteries of varying capacities (2-30Ah) from a varied DC input.

Given that I need to supply CC/CV to charge these batteries I plan on using a buck/boost converter such as this one:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/1500W-30A-Voltage-Step-Up-Converter-Boost-CC-CV-Power-Supply-Module/292853831480?epid=13026837672&hash=item442f72d738:g:EfsAAOSwtYZcCiBH

Connected directly to a BMS (or several in parallel) which offers charge balancing:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Waterproof-BMS-6S-25A-35A-45A-60A-24V-25-2V-Li-ion-Battery-PCB-PCM-with-Balance/153021323145?hash=item23a0c81789:m:md0CttkjID5Rn60hEU8c1BA

My questions are as follows:

1) Will the above parts safely charge a 6s li-ion battery, assuming current supply is set appropriately for their cells' capacity?

2) Is it necessary to add a separate system for charge termination at low current (the above BMS claims to offer overcharge protection but I am dubious, not to mention 4.25v seems high)?
If this is necessary what would be the easiest way to integrate such a function?

3) Final question - what would I need to adapt about this system for charging LiFePo batteries in series?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: Li-Ion batteries are **very dangerous**. Improper manipulation can lead to overheating, fires and explosions. If you are not 100% sure of what you are doing, don't!

Comment: @jcaron Unfortunately, that misconception is widely spread. Yes, failure modes of Lithiums often include fire and chain reaction. But treating good Lithiums 'right' is easy: Limit current and voltage and you're pretty safe. - If a cell should be already damaged, 'safe' charging, not causing a fire failure, is indeed more challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the comments I feel the need to point out:

### Warning

"Good", i.e. healthy, i.e. non-defective, cells are safe and easy to charge, see below.

**If a Lithium cell is damaged**, through previous mechanical, thermal, or electrical abuse (over-discharge, over-charge, over-current), which may not be visible at all, charging that cell (as well as using it, sometimes even just storing them) bears **significant risk of** thermal runaway with **fire**, likely causing a chain reaction of the other cells in a battery pack.

A good/sophisticated charger will employ different mechanisms to try and detect defective cells and abort charging. Some symptoms of some defects can be detected by the charger before it's too late. Some may not be so pronounced and go undetected. That's why even with the most expensive/sophisticated chargers there's still a chance of disaster.

### Answer to OP

> 1) Will the above parts safely charge a 6s li-ion battery, assuming
>   current supply is set appropriately for their cells' capacity?

Yes.

> 2) Is it necessary to add a separate system for charge termination at
>   low current (the above BMS claims to offer overcharge protection but I
>   am dubious, not to mention 4.25v seems high)? If this is necessary
>   what would be the easiest way to integrate such a function?

No, not necessary. As long as you make sure to **never apply more than 4.2V** to a cell, you're safe. This means that the PSU in your case must be set to never output more than 6*4.2V = 25.2V, besides limiting the current to appropriate value for the batteries to charge. The BMS will take care of balancing to ensure that you don't end up with one cell at e.g. 4.0V and another one at 4.4V (i.e. apparently "safe" 8.4V for a 2s).

Consider the overcharge protection of the BMS (@4.25V) as a safety feature to prevent fire, not as part of the charging algorithm.

Don't rely on this to normally terminate your charge. It's like a circuit breaker in your home: You don't stick a screwdriver into your wall outlet to turn off the light, although it will seem to work as desired most of the time.

You may want to play it extra safe or to be gentle to your batteries to prolong their life and set V[max] to 4.15V or even 4.10V per cell. This significantly reduces stress and may double the cell's life by limiting the SoC to about 90% instead of 100% (=4.2V per cell).

Note that while terminating charging is not *required* as long as you stay at or below 4.2V per cell, holding a cell at 4.2V for extended periods will reduce the cell's useful cycle life. Hence the cells will suffer if you keep the charger running e.g. over night or even over a weekend. Apart from that, it's not too dangerous to apply 4.2V for some time even after the cell is already full. Although a safety timer does make sense as one means to detect a cell defect: If the battery is expected to be fully charged after e.g. 1 hour, and the charger detects that it does not seem to be full even after e.g. 2 hours, it should assume a defect and abort charging.

> 3) Final question - what would I need to adapt about this system for
>   charging LiFePo batteries in series?

Because LiFePo's operate at a lower maximum voltage (about 3.6V instead of 4.2V for Li-Ion), you'll need a different BMS, and you need to set the PSU's maximum output voltage to 3.6V per cell, i.e. 6*3.6V = 21.6V max.

Comment: I disagree with limiting the maximum pack voltage is safe. Even if you apply less then 6*4.2V, this does not mean a single cell will never see more than 4.2V. Li-Cells have the nasty disadvantage of large parameter spreads. It is not unheard of having two series connected cells with one being almost empty and the other almost full. Hence you need active balancing circuits for all series connected battery packs. Neglecting this is asking for an accident (i.e. potential fire) to happen.

Comment: @AttilaKinali Did you read that the OP explicitly said that he was going to use a BMS, to which he also provided a link?

Comment: Yes I did. That's why I was addressing only your comment on the total voltage. It can be misleading and people might think it's safe to just limit the total voltage, while it's not. I probably should have written it more clearly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AttilaKinali I think I made it clear through "never apply more than 4.2V to a cell" and "The BMS [which the OP indends to use] should take care of balancing to ensure that ...". Don't you think?

Comment: Most of your comments are OK, but the suggestion that LiIon can be safely held at 4.2V on charge is bad advice and will lead to life reduction for moderate extended periods and rapid destruction if left allowed to CV tail down to low current levels. I realise that you have warned about not leaving them overnight or for a weekend BUT you need to emphasis charge termination at some Imin  || Terminating at eg C/10 is pushing cells quite hard and shortens life. Even terminating at C/4 is is 'enthusiastic' and C/2 termination meets most needs. || Your recommenation re Vmax of 4.15 or 4.1V is good.

Comment: +1 ....................

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thanks for the input. All sources I found in the past indicate the same: A cell suffers at 4.2V. It doesn't matter much if you externally apply 4.2V to a full cell or take a cell to 4.2V and store it away. (Of course, self-discharge will relieve some of that stress over time, but not within hours or a few days but more over weeks and months.) Limiting V[max] to e.g. 4.15V generally reduces cell stress, and much more so if you keep 'charging' for longer periods.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What do you mean by "C/2" as termination criteria? I'm under the impression that something around C/2 is the recommended/permissible *maximum* charging current for many cells.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon What would be the most convenient method for decoupling the battery when a chosen Imin is reached?
As an additional question, is leaving a LiFePo battery at 3.6V detrimental in a similar way?

Comment: @JimmyB  You are correct - permissible charge rate is cell model specific. Usually either C/1 or C/2 are specified as Imax in CC mode.  I'll open a few data sheets in the order I find them and see what they say. || Panasonic NCR18650B 3250 mAh -> C/2 max | Samsung INR18650-30Q usual C/2, max 4C/3 (full charge period). | LG HD2 2 Ah - Nominal : 1A 4.2V, 50mA End-current (CC-CV) / Fast : 4A 4.2V, 100mA End-current (CC-CV) <- ie C/2 and 2C ! - I_terminate = C/40 & C/20 = Rpad Warrior range :-).

Comment: @Thom Stop the charger - if at output a series FET is easy and cheap. | I would lean towards removing voltage from LiFePO4s BUT they have a "strange" end of charge mode - they will charge all the way to 4.2V with very very little capacity above 3.6V. I have found nothing in formal specs on this and minimal mention in literature. I SUSPECT that there is perhaps a very small amount of active material outside the LiFePO4 Olivine matrix which effectively adds a low capacity LiIon front end, | ...

Comment: That said - I have had LiFePO4 fail rapidly and unexpectedly in a situation where I left 3.6V on it.  I do not know why and I hope to investigate that further. For now I'd remove Vchg and it's easy t o do.

Comment: So  I either need to set the CV to a lower value per cell (~4.1V) or I need to connect a relay/FET to the charger to decouple it when Imin = C/10 - C/2? Thanks a lot for the information.

Comment: @Thom Yes. Both say 4.1V AND charge termination would be wise. Reducing vmax from 4.2V to 4.1V substantially increases charge cycles with a small reduction in per cycle capacity. Going to 4.0v gives even longer overall life but with a more noticeable drop in capacity.  There are SE EE answers covering this

Comment: @Thom Yes and no. The lower charge current limit, e.g. C/20, is to detect when the cell is full, i.e. it holds 100% of the specified capacity. You could continue charging @ 4.2V, but the current would slowly approach, but theoretically never reach, 0 as the cell's voltage slowly approaches 4.20000...V. Thus, current-based termination is basically equivalent to voltage-based termination @ e.g. 4.18V, i.e. at the cell voltage at which the current drops to e.g. C/10. Voltage limited charging is thus safe, you just don't know when 100% SoC is actually reached, or won't reach it but only like 98%.

Answer (score -1):

I would not recommend to jury rig a charger for Li-based chemistries. Li-ion and LiFePo batteries are very sensitive to being properly charged and, due to the large energy they pack, can be disastrous if they even feel like being unkindly handled. While what you propose is safe for NiCd and NiMH chemistries, it is not for Li chemistries. If you want to build a charger, first read up how such chargers are supposed to work (there are good articles and appnotes from the charger chip manufacturers, Ti and Linear/Analog are good places to start). If you cannot find a board with a suitable charger chip somewhere, you can build your own PCB (not too difficult, just requires some care).

For the first experiments, I urge you to use battery packs where each cell has its individual protection circuit. Or use them in an environment where a metal fire wouldn't cause damage or safety issues.

BTW: there is a reason why chargers for Li batteries are custom builds for a specific type of battery. Understand why this is, before attempting to build your own charger.

Comment: I disagree: "are very sensitive to being properly charged" - Lithiums are much easier to "properly charge" than e.g. NiMH. And "due to the large energy they pack, can be disastrous" is also not the right conclusion. It's not the (electrical) energy in them that causes disasters, it's the fact that they contain flammable material (electrolyte) and bring their own oxidizer which makes it very hard to extinguish them.